# Could the cursor property be dependant of float?

Tags: css

Has anybody experienced a case, when 'cursor' property stops working when 'float' property is added? And I mean only the 'cursor' property.

(I am not adding my code, as it's a long story and it's too complex for such a small problem, so am just wondering if anybody knows if and how these properties could be dependant.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kind of: It could be that the float causes z-index issues, or makes the object disappear underneath another invisible object (that happens often) which invalidates the cursor property (because to the browser, the mouse is over the invisible element, not the one you defined the `cursor` for.)

If the element is not obscured by another element, though, and reacts properly to a `:hover` property for example, then the answer is no - I've never heard of any strange behaviour related to `cursor` and `float` specifically.

Comment: Thanks! I did really have an invisible object in my case there, which I forgot about and not working cursor was driving me nuts =)